# vuejs nativescript firebase webapp to android/ios app

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuejs2, nativescript

I am new with NativeScript, Vue.js, and Firebase.

I have a built web app using Vue.js and Firebase, but now I don't know how to integrate the code to NativeScript using the same code of Vue.js.

**Is there a way to do this? And how can I start it?**

Comment: Check this template https://github.com/hmendes00/nativescript-vue-firebase-template

Answer (score 0):

I worked with @jlooper over the last couple of weekends to get a definitive answer for this because there wasn't one anywhere previously:

https://medium.com/@groksrc/how-to-set-up-nativescript-vue-js-and-firebase-465354d4296b

There are instructions on [Eddy's plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/) README are mostly complete, but there are a few gotchas that I point out in my blog post that you need to be aware of. Also, the readme isn't specific to vue so it's not immediately clear where to put the Firebase files. Those are all explained in the blog post as well as a couple of links to other small projects from Jen that will get you started.